# Ember: how to test a function involves setting variable for new route

Tags: ember.js

I have this code:

```
this.transitionToRoute('question').then(function(newRoute) {
    newRoute.controller.set('name',name__ );}
```

in an action func
and I try to unit test it:

This is what I have now :

```
let ctrl = this.subject();

var calledTransitionToRoute = "";
ctrl.transitionToRoute = function(route) {
calledTransitionToRoute = route;
};
ctrl.send('routeToConfirm');
return wait().then(function() {
assert.equal(calledTransitionToRoute, 'question');
});
```

I just dont know how to test if the new route receives the name variable.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think the problem is: "After overwriting transitionToRoute, we cannot call then() on it"

Comment: You have to return a fulfilling promise. But I think you could test this in a better way, without overwriting the function.

Comment: @wuarmin could u give a example?

Comment: we are talking about an integration, not an acceptance test, aren't we?

Comment: @wuarmin unit preferably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this out. if I understood you correctly, this should do what you want:

Subject under test:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({

  actions: {
    changeRoute() {
      this.transitionToRoute('bar').then((newRoute) => {
        newRoute.controller.set('name', "helloWorld" );
      });
    },
  }
});
```

controller-unit test

```
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import { resolve } from 'rsvp';
import EmberObject from '@ember/object';
import wait from 'ember-test-helpers/wait';

moduleFor('controller:foo', 'Unit | Controller | foo', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
});

// Replace this with your real tests.
test('changeRoute action should change to correct route and set controller-name-prop', function(assert) {
  let controller = this.subject();

  const TestRoute = EmberObject.extend();
  const TestController = EmberObject.extend();

  let testRoute = TestRoute.create({ controller: TestController.create() })

  controller.transitionToRoute = function(newRoute) {
    assert.equal(newRoute, 'bar', 'transitionToRoute was called with correct route-name');
    return resolve(testRoute);
  }

  controller.send('changeRoute');

  assert.ok(controller);

  return wait().then(() => {
    assert.equal(testRoute.get('controller.name'), 'helloWorld', ' controller name was set');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! One change I made: `import resolve` does not work for me. So I used `Ember.RSVP.resolve`

Comment: What ember version are you using? < 2.17? It is the new import style. https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2017/10/11/ember-2-16-released.html